# Webpage content cramped on window resize

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am working on asp.net web application. 
When i re-size windows horizontally, all the web contents comes together but when i re-size vertically, vertical side scroll appears.

How to make horizontal scroll appear on re-size?

Below is my .css code

```
html {
    background-image: url("../Images/water2.jpg") ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /*for webKit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover; /*Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover; /*opera*/
     background-size: cover; /*generic*/
    background-color:#668B8B;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    padding: 25px 5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;

}

body {
    background-image: url("../Images/headercool.jpeg");
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    overflow:auto;
    background-size: 100%;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;



}

a {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

    a {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

    a:link, a:visited,
    a:active, a:hover {
        color: #333;
    }

    a:hover {
        background-color: #c7d1d6;
    }

header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}

mark {
    background-color: #a6dbed;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: medium;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

    h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

#body {
    background: url("../Images/pop.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /*for webKit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover; /*Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover; /*opera*/
     background-size: cover; /*generic*/
    background-color: #C2DFFF;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height: auto;
    min-height:600px;

}

    .main-content {
        background: url("../Images/accent.png") no-repeat;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 30px;

    }

    .featured + .main-content {
        background: url("../Images/heroAccent.png") no-repeat;
    }

header .content-wrapper {
    padding-top: 0px; 



}

footer {
    clear: both;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    font-size: .8em;
    height:0px;
    top: 384px;
    left: 5px;
}


/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-title {
    color: #c8c8c8;
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #c8c8c8;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `min-width`, like this:

```
body {
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

This will add horizontal scroll bars to the browser once you resize the body of the page below 1000 pixels wide.

Here is the documentation for [CSS min-width property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp)